# Measure data use of an android app (component-wise)

Tags: android, traffic-measurement

Is there any way I could measure the data being used by the components in my android app? If yes, how can I do it?

For example, Say I have an app A with X and Y components, I would like to know that what amount of internet data the component X uses and what amount of internet data Y uses.

Comment: What do you consider a "component" to be?

Comment: I would want something like this. Let us say in my app I have a component/service which can download images from the internet and show them on my app. I would like to know how much internet data the service/component uses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [use `TrafficStats`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) for this, either to programmatically record the amount of bandwidth before and after some operation (e.g., "download images from the internet"), or to use the tag structure to help show this sort of breakdown in DDMS.